# How do i fix backgroundworker is busy c# code

Tags: c#

i keep getting background worker is busy when i run my code. any help?

```
       struct FtpSetting
    {
        public string Server { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }

    FtpSetting _inputParameter;

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).FileName;
        string fullName = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).FullName;
        string userName = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Username;
        string password = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Password;
        string server = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Server;
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", server, fileName)));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fullName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        double total = (double)fs.Length;
        int byteRead = 0;
        double read = 0;
        do
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
                //Upload file & update process bar
                byteRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
                read += (double)byteRead;
                double percentage = read / total * 100;
                backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)percentage);
            }
        }
        while (byteRead != 0);
        fs.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = $"Uploaded {e.ProgressPercentage} %";
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressBar.Update();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Upload complete !";
    }

    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = "C:\\Users\\bluevels\\Pictures\\";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {

            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileName);
            _inputParameter.Username = txtUserName.Text;
            _inputParameter.Password = txtPassword.Text;
            _inputParameter.Server = txtServer.Text;
            _inputParameter.FileName = fi.Name;
            _inputParameter.FullName = fi.FullName;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_inputParameter);

        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

i keep getting the error from this line

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_inputParameter);
```

Comment: The `FtpWebRequest` and the Stream/FileStream have an async version: `[FtpWebRequest].GetRequestStreamAsync()`, `[FileStream].ReadAsync()` and `[FtpStream].WriteAsync()`. You can just await an async upload method if you want a sequential upload proc, or enqueue some Tasks and/or await `TaskWhenAll()`. Of course, if not sequential, you'll need more than one progress bar, or one that updates the overall progress. But that's another story :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured it our. all i had to do was put the loop in the backgroundworker as seen in the code below.

```
    struct FtpSetting
    {
        public string Server { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }

    FtpSetting _inputParameter;

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = "";
        string fullName = "";

        string dir = "C:\\Users\\bluevels\\Desktop\\ww\\";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {

            string FileName = "C:\\Users\\bluevels\\Desktop\\ww\\" + Path.GetFileName(file);


            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileName);

            fileName = fi.Name;
            fullName = fi.FullName;





            string userName = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Username;
            string password = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Password;
            string server = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Server;
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", server, fileName)));
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fullName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            double total = (double)fs.Length;
            int byteRead = 0;
            double read = 0;
            do
            {
                if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    //Upload file & update process bar
                    byteRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                    ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
                    read += (double)byteRead;
                    double percentage = read / total * 100;
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)percentage);
                }
            }
            while (byteRead != 0);
            fs.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = $"Uploaded {e.ProgressPercentage} %";
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressBar.Update();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Upload complete !";
    }

    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                _inputParameter.Username = txtUserName.Text;
                _inputParameter.Password = txtPassword.Text;
                _inputParameter.Server = txtServer.Text;
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_inputParameter);


    }
```

the percentage calculation also works fine with every file.

Answer (score 3):

By placing `RunWorkerAsync()` inside the `foreach`, you are attempting to start multiple copies of the worker using the same instance whilst it is already running.

Consider moving the loop into the worker itself:

```
class FtpSetting
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string[] Files { get; set; }
}

private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
       return;

      string dir = "C:\\Users\\bluevels\\Pictures\\";
      string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);

     _inputParameter.Username = txtUserName.Text;
     _inputParameter.Password = txtPassword.Text;
     _inputParameter.Server = txtServer.Text;
     _inputParameter.Files = files;
     backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_inputParameter);
}
```

Naturally the body of the worker will need to be changed as `e` is a list of files now.  The rest of the properties can be read directly from instance fields.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var setting = (FtpSetting)e.Argument;
    ...
    for (int fileNum = 0; fileNum < setting.Files.Length; fileNum++)
    {
         if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
             break;

         do
             ...
             // use setings.Files[fileNum]
             // also divide percentage done by setting.Files.Length e.g.
             double percentage = (100/setting.Files.Length)+fileNum + (read / total * 100);
             ...
    }

  }
```

That way if you ever decide to do true concurrent downloading from multiple sites (you'll need multiple workers or perhaps consider *TPL DataFlow*) there will be minimal code changes.

Comment: if i take the loop out i cant get **_inputParameter.FileName = fi.Name;
     _inputParameter.FullName = fi.FullName;**  since i get ** fi**

Comment: @Bluevels remove FileName and FullName from `FtpSetting` and get them from `_inputParameter.Files` inside `backgroundWorker_DoWork`.

Comment: @DourHighArch can you show me how to get them in the backgroundworker

Comment: @Bluevels I showed you enough `backgroundWorker_DoWork` to get you going. Will probably need to tune the `percentage` calculation.

Comment: @DourHighArch okay